# Python setup.py isn't updating Flask templates/index.html

Tags: python, flask, setup.py

I'm having problems with setup.py installing a simple Flask application and creating an entry_point to run the application. Here's my directory structure:

```
<root folder>
  `-- example
      `-- __init__.py
      `-- 01
          `-- __init__.py
          `-- app.py
          `-- templates
              `-- index.html
```

Here's my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    now = datetime.now()
    return render_template("index.html", now=now)

def main():
    app.run(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's my templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your First Web Server</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Current time: {{now}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a simplified version of my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="example",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "flask==1.1.2"
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "example_01 = examples.01.app:main",
        ]
    }
)
```

And here's my MANIFEST.in file:

```
include README.md
recursive-include example/01/templates *
global-exclude *.pyc
```

Here's the problem. If I run `python setup.py install`, then `export FLASK_APP=examples/01/app` and then `flask run`, the app runs correctly and I get what I expect on the browser, a current timestamp every time I refresh the page.

However, if I run `example_02` (the console scripts entry point) the server runs, but if I navigate to the page I get content from an old version of the `01/templates/index.html` file. The really strange part to me is seemingly nothing I do changes this behavior, I can't seem to get `python setup.py install` to update the console scripts entry point to the new index.html file.

Comment: One thing I noticed when I dealt with ```python setup.py``` is old *.pyc files. I use to clean them and try to build again, so that latest content is generated. Did you covered this scenario already?

Comment: I think I might have in the variations of things I tried. I've deleted my virtual environment, done a `python setup.py clean --all`, removed the build, dist and various *.egg files related to my project. However, all of that said I didn't explicitly remove the *.pyc files, I will dig into that, thanks!